# Jquery Ajax call not allowing other links to act normally

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with many "normal" links (`<a href=XXX>`) , part of this page is fetching data via jQuery Ajax method (this call might take around 20-30 seconds ...).

I've found out that if I press one of the links while the Ajax call is still running, I cannot redirect normally to the link's address and I have to wait till the Ajax call is finished (even though it's supposed to be asynchronous... isn't it?)

I guess I have to abort the Ajax call if any link is being pressed before it is finished - anyone can enlighten me how to do so?

Cheers,

Comment: This would be somewhat easier to answer if we could see the jQuery you're using to handle the Ajax. Not to mention the html upon which it's acting. I'd suggest posting code *here* and, if you can, pointing us to a live demo. Either at your own site or, preferably, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo (those sites allow us to collaboratively edit and revise the demo and save different revisions).

Answer (score 2):

If the links do not work, your ajax call should be synchronous. Synchronous (blocking) requests (async:false) lock your browser and prevent it from doing any action.

Check your code to see if you have passed a false async parameter to .ajax function. If you return the result of the .ajax call to a variable, you should have used a blocking request.

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Example: Loads data synchronously. Blocks the browser while the requests is active. It is better to block user interaction by other means when synchronization is necessary.

```
var html = $.ajax({

  url: "some.php",

  async: false

 }).responseText;
```

Comment: Good answer, but have a look at [Stack Overfow's Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to format code; +1 =)